# What front-end profiler do you use to analyze the performance of the magento 2 site?

Tags: magento2, performance, profiler

What is the best free front-end profiler to analyze site performance magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

[Magenta already has it. See more on the official website](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/mage-profiler.html)

[You can also use the xDebug profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

*When using the xDebug profiler, it is convenient to view the dump file, for example, through IDEA*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The frontend profiler. Correct me if I'm wrong.

- I think you want to monitor CWV scores?

> The Core Web Vitals (CWV) are a set of three web performance metrics.
> Google's search engine measures these three metrics and incorporates
> them into its decisions about which pages to display in search
> results. This means search engine optimization (SEO) practitioners
> should optimize their webpages' core web vitals as part of a holistic
> strategy to improve those pages' rankings.

Their is some tool, which allow you records front-end performance:

- NewRelic browser
- Cloudflare Browser Insights
- Google search console.